# WCF to WCFCore - Help Menu

Tags: c#, wcf, menu

I am trying to migrate a webservice from WCF to WCF Core. I want to add the help menu, but I don't see that it is the same as the WCF one.

I want it to look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbeIL.png)

But it looks like this now
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vnWL.png)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IService,Service>();
        services.AddServiceModelServices();
        services.AddServiceModelMetadata();
        services.AddSingleton<IServiceBehavior, UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior>();
        SetCacheConnectionString();
        SetAdministratorUser();

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseServiceModel(serviceBuilder =>
        {

            serviceBuilder.AddService<Service>(o =>
            {
                o.DebugBehavior.HttpHelpPageEnabled = true;
                o.DebugBehavior.HttpsHelpPageEnabled = true;
                o.DebugBehavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = false;
            });
            serviceBuilder.AddServiceEndpoint<Service,IService>(new BasicHttpBinding(CoreWCF.Channels.BasicHttpSecurityMode.None), "/Custom");
        });

        var sMB = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
        sMB.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        sMB.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
    }




   [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Creates trips using the provided information.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="importRequest"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = false)]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate = "addcustom")]
        ImportResponse AddCustom(Stream stream);
    }
```

Here you can see the current result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGLR8.png)

Comment: Usually this kind of help page is implemented via **WebhttpBinding**.  Here is the relevant introductory document:[WCF Web HTTP Service Help Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-service-help-page?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Corewcf has limited support for webhttpbinding, but I found documentation that I thought would be helpful:[corewcf webhttpbinding](https://corewcf.github.io/blog/2022/04/13/webhttp)